# Figure ok in dvi but a mess in pdf and ps

Tags: graphics, dvips, dvipdf

Apologies - this is my first time posting and I'm having trouble figuring out how to put multiple images WITH the correct descriptions! So I've just put 2 - the one with the figure nicely positioned and within a frame is after compiling and viewing in Yap, the one that's all messed up and NOT in its frame is after doing dvi-to-pdf and viewing in Adobe. It is similarly messed up if I do dvi-to-ps.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{center}
          \frame{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{4step_demod.eps}}
     \caption{Schematic of symmetric phase stepping demodulation scheme. (Reproduced from \cite{Foster2012}.)}\label{fig_4step}
     \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The same as for every other figure in the document, but this one won't behave!! (I've tried replacing `\begin{center}` with `\centering`, btw). If I open the figure in ghostview, it looks lovely with a reasonable bounding box. I read on here about this "framing" business, so I added that. The dvi looks beautiful. But eps and pdf are both terrible - as you can hopefully see.

Any help appreciated. I'm not an expert user (clearly), so please go easy on me :/ (I did try searching this site for similar questions but didn't find anything to fix the problem)

Oh, and I use straight latex, not pdflatex. Compiler is miktex.

[image: Fig in pdf]

[image: Screenshot of fig in Yap]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Just to be sure, when you say that in gsview the figure shows a reasonable bounding box, do you have `EPS clip` option active?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Did you try converting your .eps file to `pdf` format, and compile with `pdfLaTeX`? The `eps-pdf-extra` does a very good job at this. With MiKTeX, you'll have to install it yourself. It can be found here: http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/epspdf-extra/

Comment: I didn't know about EPS clip, but just ticked this option and yep the figure still looks a-ok in ghostview.

Comment: I've never had any luck getting pdfLaTeX working and I haven't pursued it to date because I've managed ok with "normal" latex. Maybe now I should make time to get pdflatex working. I'll check out this eps-pdf-extra, thanks.